# Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: "Too many connections"?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am using MySQL database and hibernate and JSP.using hibernate select database store value and prepared view and display using Ajax.i am polling database every 1 seconds using Java script timer that called a ajax function and return the new responds,it result me an error

> JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"".

Help me to sort-out the above define problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you close the session (and connection) after using it
2. Make sure the maximum connection configured for mysql is sufficient
3. Use of some caching layer. It is insane to hit the database every 1 second from each user.
4. If you are making some chat application, consider comet and server-side pub-sub solutions (jmx for example).